# Are the threads in each process limited to 1 cpu?

Tags: cpu, process, threads

On a multi CPU machine, I understand that 1 process runs on 1 CPU. So does this mean that the threads in each process are limited to 1 cpu only?

Comment: Look up "cpu core". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor

Comment: If you have a quad-core cpu, for example, 1 process can spawn 4 threads that use a core each.

Comment: Processes are not limited to use a single core, threads are.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, threads behave much like processes (except they share memory while processes don't) and each thread will only run on 1 logical CPU (≈ core) at any given time. However, different threads of the same process *can* run on different logical CPUs, and sometimes that's the whole point of using threads – e.g. on a 8-core system, you might see certain processes (encoders, servers) creating 8 "worker" threads, one for each logical CPU.

Comment: If you have a dual processor motherboard with 2 cpu's, each containing 4 cores, a process could spawn 8 threads that use every single core, right? So I think the answer should be no, because a process is not limited to using 1 cpu (but each thread is limited to one core, which is probably what OP meant)